# Line chart not plotting in sequence

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to implement Line chart, from API I am getting response in sequence but on `Line Chart` its not plotting in sequence.

[Here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqzjh9fm/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data isn't sorted in timestamp ascending order as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Date_based_data). Sorting your data will fix the problem.

```
chart.data = data.sort((lhs,rhs) => {
 return (new Date(rhs.endDate)) - (new Date(lhs.endDate));
});
```